# Connect to Access 2013 with Python: Data source name not found

Tags: python, ms-access-2013, pyodbc

I use this code to connect to Access 2013:

```
conn_str = r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\_DELOITTE\Statistics.mdb;"
self.conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

I get the following error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I use Windows 8, Intel processor, 32-bit Access, and Python 2.7.

In Administrative Tools I have `ODBC Data Sources (32-bit)` and `ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)` both pointing at `%windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe`. Only "System DSN" is filled in, but no "User DSN".

[image: System DSN]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be incompatibility if you are using 64bit Python. I just tested something similar on my machine.

This isn't conclusive since these are different versions of Python, but it is a lead to follow. Here's what I tested:

32bit Python 2.7, on a 32bit MS Access driver.
Connection successful, no errors.

64bit Python 3.4, on a 32bit MS Access driver.
Returned Error: "pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source na
me not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10729505)

Comment: Actually. It can provide an answer to the question, if the OP is using 64bit Python. Given that I cannot comment on the OP's question (due to lack of rep), how else am I to determine if the OP is using a 64bit or 32bit Python?

Comment: Get more rep or use chat.

Comment: It is only your opinion that this is not an answer, however, this is a plausible solution to the problem that the OP is having, with potential evidence of its effect. If, for some reason, the OP comes back and determines that this is not a plausible solution, I will of course delete it.

Comment: That is a good strategy. You should be aware of the fact that deleting it may not be left up to you at some point.

Comment: Yes, I use Python 64-bit! I will try to get Python 32-bit and ee if the connection works.